# Regular expression to extract URL from an HTML link

Tags: python, regex

I’m a newbie in Python. I’m learning regexes, but I need help here.

Here comes the HTML source:

```
<a href="http://www.ptop.se" target="_blank">http://www.ptop.se</a>
```

I’m trying to code a tool that only prints out `http://ptop.se`. Can you help me please?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430966/regex-for-links-in-html-text

Comment: I've been away from SO for a while, it's good to see I've missed nothing, and people are STILL asking how to parse HTML with regex every damn day.

Comment: @bobince Multiple times a day, it is so bad I created two questions that I can redirect people to and a form answer that points them there.

Answer (score 86):

If you're only looking for one:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

If you have a long string, and want every instance of the pattern in it:

```
import re
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s)
print(', '.join(urls))
```

Where `s` is the string that you're looking for matches in.

*Quick explanation of the regexp bits:*

> `r'...'` is a "raw" string. It stops you having to worry about escaping characters quite as much as you normally would. (`\` especially -- in a raw string a `\` is just a `\`.  In a regular string you'd have to do `\\` every time, and that gets *old* in regexps.)
>
> "`href=[\'"]?`" says to match "href=", possibly followed by a `'` or `"`.  "Possibly" because it's hard to say how horrible the HTML you're looking at is, and the quotes aren't strictly required.
>
> Enclosing the next bit in "`()`" says to make it a "group", which means to split it out and return it separately to us. It's just a way to say "this is the part of the pattern I'm interested in."
>
> "`[^\'" >]+`" says to match any characters that *aren't* `'`, `"`, `>`, or a space. Essentially this is a list of characters that are an end to the URL. It lets us avoid trying to write a regexp that reliably matches a full URL, which can be a bit complicated.

The suggestion in another answer to use BeautifulSoup isn't bad, but it does introduce a higher level of external requirements. Plus it doesn't help you in your stated goal of learning regexps, which I'd assume this specific html-parsing project is just a part of.

It's pretty easy to do:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_to_parse)
for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    print(tag['href'])
```

Once you've installed BeautifulSoup, anyway.

Comment: Part of learning regexes is learning when not to use them, this is a case where you shouldn't use them.

Comment: some pages are so badly formatted that even BeautifulSoup can't find the links in there. Then you have to resort to something.

Comment: Small improvement to the regexp: `re.findall(r'href\s?=\s?[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', show_notes)`, which allows a space before and/or after the equals sign.

Comment: Are you sure it is "match.group(0)" instead of "match.group(1)"?

Comment: Would it not make more sense, and is it not more correct, to write `if match:` as `if match is not None:` instead?

Comment: @blizz doesn't really matter; re.search will return a match object or None, and there's no other possible falsey returns (i.e. we don't need to distinguish between None and False here). As such, `if match:` is more compact and understandable.

Answer (score 13):

Don't use regexes, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). That, or be so crufty as to spawn it out to, say, w3m/lynx and pull back in what w3m/lynx renders. First is more elegant probably, second just worked a heck of a lot faster on some unoptimized code I wrote a while back.

Answer (score 13):

this should work, although there might be more elegant ways.

```
import re
url='<a href="http://www.ptop.se" target="_blank">http://www.ptop.se</a>'
r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")')
r.findall(url)
```

Comment: (?<=href=["']).*?(?=["']) takes care of single quoated href also

Answer (score 12):

John Gruber (who wrote Markdown, which is made of regular expressions and is used right here on Stack Overflow) had a go at producing a regular expression that recognises URLs in text:

http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

If you just want to grab the URL (i.e. you’re not really trying to parse the HTML), this might be more lightweight than an HTML parser.

Answer (score 3):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

In particular you will want to look at the Python answers: [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773565#773565), [HTMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773344#773344), and [lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774062#774062).

Answer (score 3):

this regex can help you, you should get the first group by \1 or whatever method you have in your language.

```
href="([^"]*)
```

example:

```
<a href="http://www.amghezi.com">amgheziName</a>
```

result:

```
http://www.amghezi.com
```

Answer (score 2):

There's tonnes of them on [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are tons of them on [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/). That only proves that RE's should not be used to do that. Use SGMLParser or BeautifulSoup or write a parser - but don't use RE's. The ones that seems to work are extremely compliated and still don't cover all cases.

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty well with using optional matches (prints after `href=`) and gets the link only. Tested on http://pythex.org/

```
(?:href=['"])([:/.A-z?<_&\s=>0-9;-]+)
```

Oputput:

> Match 1. /wiki/Main_Page
>
> Match 2. /wiki/Portal:Contents
>
> Match 3. /wiki/Portal:Featured_content
>
> Match 4. /wiki/Portal:Current_events
>
> Match 5. /wiki/Special:Random
>
> Match 6. //donate.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FundraiserRedirector?utm_source=donate&utm_medium=sidebar&utm_campaign=C13_en.wikipedia.org&uselang=en

Comment: When entering this regular expression in a python program (not through the site you mentioned) it will give an error due to the usage of text quotation marks `'` or `"`. To fix this the regex should be: `regex='(?:href=[\'"])([:/.A-z?<_&\s=>0-9;-]+)'` by adding a slant \ before the  `'` or the `"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.

```
<a[^>]+href=["'](.*?)["']
```