# Regular Expression to extract HREFS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that can extract the href from this:

```
<a href="/tr/blog.php?post=3593&user=930">
```

There are hundreds of links on the page so I need to extract only those that contain

```
/tr/blog.php
```

So in the end I should be left with a list of links that start in /tr/blog

Thanks for any help. It's really puzzling me.

This is the RegEx I am currently using, but it matches all.

```
/href\s*=\s*\"*[^\">]*/ig;
```

Comment: VeeArr, I've no idea what it means lol. I was using another account on SO, but recently had my other GMail hacked so had to revert back to this one.

Comment: Also the use of the "Search" box. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link.

Comment: @James: it means accept some answers as being the "accepted answer" for your question. Pick one and click the check box next to it.

Comment: Use a DOM library and grab all anchors then extract href attribute. Please specify language.

Comment: Oh, thanks John, I was unaware of that. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like `href=\"(/tr/blog.php[^"]*)\"` (will capture to Group 1), but in general [you should not use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body> <a href="/tr/blog.php?lol">fslk</a> 

<script>

    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), captured = [];

    for ( var i = 0, l = anchors.length, href, r = /tr\/blog\.php/; i<l; ++i ) {
         href = this.href;
         if ( r.test( href ) ) {
             captured.push( this )
         }
    }

    // do what u want with captured links
    for ( var l = captured.length; l--; ) {
        alert( captured[l].href )
    }

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but now that it's the future, you don't even need the regular expression:

`document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='/tr/blog.php']")` will give you the links that *contain* that string, or you can find those that *begin* with that string `document.querySelectorAll("[href^='/tr/blog.php']")`.