# Parsing uncommon symbol using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a link like this  `<a href=abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme´_beautiful.jpg>` , where there is this unusual symbol `´` , which is not even present in a standard English keyboard. 
It is the mirror reflection of the symbol that `Ctrl+k` produces in this editor .
So after I ran this code found on stackoverflow:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<a href=abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme´_beautiful.jpg>");
for a in soup.findAll('a'):                                                                       
    print a['href']
```

The output is `abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme` but I want to have `abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme´_beautiful.jpg` . The website that I'm scraping is in a `.br` domain . Some of the writings is in Portugese , even though the links are in English , but that uncommon symbol may not be a valid English language symbol. Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Edit: I looked at the representation that Python string produced me , it was `<a href=abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme\xb4_beautiful.jpg>`

One way around is to produce custom regex , and this snippet is also from stackoverflow:

```
import re
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s)
```

If it is impossible to modify beautifulsoup regex , how can I modify the above regex to incorporate the `\xb4` symbol. ( s here is the string in question )

Comment: Can you post a link to the webpage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link -- this is stackoverflow website and this is website I am trying to scrape http://www.atlasdermatologico.com.br/listar.asp?acao=mostrar&arquivo=sweet%B4s_syndrome48.jpg -- do not look into other links in the webpage ; its gross for medical professional only . I am not able to incorporate %B4s in my regex , I saw the string representation of \xb4 escaped in my python string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of BeautifulSoup and install `html5lib`, which is a very lenient parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('http://www.atlasdermatologico.com.br/listar.asp?acao=indice').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = a.get('href')

    if '\\' in repr(href):
        print(repr(href))
```

It correctly prints out the links with `\xb4` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks it works nice , but there is a problem how to convince my browser to consider http://www.atlasdermatologico.com.br/listar.asp?acao=mostrar&arquivo=wells´_syndrome7.jpg is actually a link i.e how to subsitute ´ with %B4s . Clicking that particular link in Chrome renders the webpage properly , but if I literally put that link in omnibox , it does not work . Is there any built in function in Python that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can include **[\u0000-\uFFFF]** as a subrange in re pattern or only include \xb4 as **[\u00b4]**

Comment: \ub4 should be \xb4 or \u00b4, right? \u expects 4 hex digits, like in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp doesn't care what follows `href=`, as long as it ends with a space (or are in quotes), so it matches \xb4 just like any other character:

```
>>> s = "<a href=abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme\xb4_beautiful.jpg>"
>>> print s.decode("latin-1")
<a href=abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme´_beautiful.jpg>
>>> urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s)
>>> urls
['abc.asp?xyz=foobar&baz=lookatme\xb4_beautiful.jpg']
```

(btw, \xb4 is an [acute accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b4/index.htm))