# How to make a regular expression to take me href, src, css links python

Tags: python

I need to take the links src, css, href, a html page and save them to a text file.

I need to do with regular expressions (regex).
Thanks!

Comment: You should try something

Comment: What we do here is tell you why your code isn't wokring. No code? Can't help ...

Comment: You can go through there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

p = re.compile(ur'.*(src|css|href|a html).*')

test_str1 = '<a html>'
test_str2 = 'String without any tags'

if re.match(p, test_str1) is not None:
    print test_str1

if re.match(p, test_str2) is not None:
    print test_str2
>> <a html>
```

Here is a solution for python 2.7, 
I assume that you understand the regex part but if not here is a good tutorial [site](https://regex101.com/) that you can use to test your regex.

Comment: I forgot to mention that python is for version 3.5 :/