# Python - Regex matching urls in page source code

Tags: python, regex

I use this pattern to match every url in a given webpage:

```
import re

source = """
<p>https://example.com</p>
... some code
<font color="E80000">https://example.com</font></a>
"""

urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', source)
```

This has worked for me pretty well until now. I found that sometimes it doesn't match the exact url. Like in the example it match as url `https://example.com</p>` and `https://example.com</font></a>` inlcuding the closing tags but I can't figure out what is the problem in the regex. I took this code from another stack question.

Comment: You use a hyphen inside a character class between two symbols, `[$-_]`, that creates a range that can match `<` and `>`, and all ASCII digits and uppercase letters, and more. Replace `[$-_@.&+]` with `[-$_@.&+]`.

Comment: see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link

Comment: u can also check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python

Comment: URLs should be in <a></a> quotes.. Do you have an special input or something?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This matches only the base url, like https://example.com/1 would match only https://example.com

Comment: @bobmarti this code would not match urls in iframes (like in src="http://example.com")

Comment: @Hyperion: Sure, that is why there are other comments. But the main idea is - forget about parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: maybe this is helpul to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
import re

source = """
<p>https://example.com</p>
... some code
<font color="E80000">https://example.com</font>
https://example.com</p></a>
https://example.com</font></a>
"""
urls = re.findall('(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?', source)
print urls
```