# kate - regex - find and replace portion of URL from href to ">

Tags: html, regex, replace, regex-group, kate

I have many links contained in .html and .txt files that I would like to modify. I mostly use Kate as my text editor thus I've asked this question with the `kate` tag. Below is a sample of the links:

```html
<li>
  <a href="http://sk1project.org/">
            sK1
        </a> is an open source vector graphics editor similar to CorelDRAW, Adobe Illustrator, or Freehand. First of all sK1 is oriented for PostScript processing. UniConvertor is a universal vector graphics translator. It uses sK1 engine to convert
  one format to another. Development of the import/export modules for this program goes through different stages, quality and feature coverage are different among formats.
</li>
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project">
            The Tango Desktop Project
        </a> exists to help create a consistent graphical user interface experience for free and Open Source software. While the look and feel of an application is determined by many individual components, some organization is necessary in order to
  unify the appearance and structure of individual icon sets used within those components. The Tango Desktop Project defines an icon style guideline to which artists and designers can adhere. A sample implementation of the style is available as an icon
  theme based upon a standardized icon naming specification. In addition, the project provides transitional utilities to assist in creating icon themes for existing desktop environments, such as GNOME and KDE.
</li>
```

I found 
[Regular expression to extract URL from an HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link) | python - Regular expression to extract URL from an HTML link - Stack Overflow so I know how to capture the text from href to "> using `href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+">)`, but I don't know how to keep the text from href to " prior to the > and add in the following text: ' rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">'.

I have how the end result should look below:

```html
<li>
  <a href="http://sk1project.org/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
            sK1
        </a> is an open source vector graphics editor similar to CorelDRAW, Adobe Illustrator, or Freehand. First of all sK1 is oriented for PostScript processing. UniConvertor is a universal vector graphics translator. It uses sK1 engine to convert
  one format to another. Development of the import/export modules for this program goes through different stages, quality and feature coverage are different among formats.
</li>
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">
            The Tango Desktop Project
        </a> exists to help create a consistent graphical user interface experience for free and Open Source software. While the look and feel of an application is determined by many individual components, some organization is necessary in order to
  unify the appearance and structure of individual icon sets used within those components. The Tango Desktop Project defines an icon style guideline to which artists and designers can adhere. A sample implementation of the style is available as an icon
  theme based upon a standardized icon naming specification. In addition, the project provides transitional utilities to assist in creating icon themes for existing desktop environments, such as GNOME and KDE
</li>
```

How can this be done with regex in Kate?

Thank you.

Comment: `I found Regular expression to extract URL from an HTML link` No you didn't, you found junk !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing html using regex isn't a recommended thing but since you are using `Kate` editor, you can capture the `<a` tag with `href` attribute using this regex,

```
(<a\s+.*?href=(['"]?)\S*\2)
```

And replace it with this,

```
\1 rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
```

I've never used Kate editor so not sure whether `\1` will work or `$1`

Let me know if this works.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tfEhEl/1)**

Comment: @sln: Whats bad? Can you explain with a practical example of why OP can't match an `<a` tag here? Keep in mind that OP is using an editor. What solution do you propose here?

Comment: Sure thing. Valid html tags don't allow quotes inside of quotes. And you're not actually matching an attribute inside an html tag. See the link I posted. I can give you a valid way to do it, but you won't understand it.

Comment: You can take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/OXLAV9/1. Any questions, let me know.

Comment: @sln: Where in the world you get those kind of URLs that contains quotes in the URLs? Which you already say are invalid in URLs? Also, remember, there is a big difference in matching vs validation. It is not that OP has a field which needs to be validated by a user input with a valid URL only. Instead all OP wants to do is just match the URL and have that extra attribute within it.

Comment: @sln: Your regex is unnecessarily complicated and isn't needed at all, plus matches invalid tag `<::::::::::: href="http://sk1project.org/">` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/OXLAV9/2)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the URL, which can exist as content. It has to do with grabbing the _href_ attribute. To do that you need to parse the tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190116/discussion-between-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi-and-sln).

Comment: `:::::::::::` is a valid tag name ! Dump it into a browser.

Comment: The `[\w:]` is just a catchall anyway. The w3c is really a shit load of Unicode characters. I can give you them if you want to use it instead.

Comment: @sln: OP is talking about matching `<a` tag which contains `href` attribute then why bother suggesting him tag names like `:::::`? I don't know if w3c allows `::::::` as a tag name or not but I've never seen a tag name like that and it would really be stupid to use `::::::` as a tag name to represent links in an html page. Please read OP's post carefully, and see what he is talking about. And come in discussion page I've invited you rather than spilling the oil here :)

Comment: @sln: Your regex indeed has even more matching issues. Your regex doesn't even work for `<a href=http://sk1project.org/>` where there are no single or double quotes surrounding href attribute value. And your regex behaves weird and catches unintended text when href value contains doublequotes. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/OXLAV9/3) And even your regex captures singlequotes in the value of href attribute. I am wondering what were you really trying to do?

Comment: I wasn't here to read the OP's post carefully. I spent 2 seconds reading it until I knew what it was in its entirety. I'm here to show _you_ the error in your regex buddy !!

Comment: @sln: My solution works well for OP's examples and any such genuine looking html containing `<a` tags and like I already said, OP is trying to match and not validate, both of which are two completely different exercises and it works pretty well for matching and giving the expected output like OP wanted. Lets please carry out our discussion in chat as its not good to spil oil here. Reply me in chat please and don't post any more messages here.

Comment: Your solution is _junk_, you don't know jack !! And `href=http://sk1project.org` is not an attrib/value, neither is this `href = http://sk1project.org`

Comment: @Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi  The answer that you provided worked for me in the Kate text editor. Thank you.

Comment: @iembry: So glad that my solution worked well for you. Let me know in case you experience any issue later anytime.